# Create Custom Single Page Link foreach custom Database table results id

Tags: plugins

I displayed a foreach loop result in a custom page from a fresh created table in the database everything work good but now i would like to create a single page from each results.

In my table i made the link to the futur single page like :

```
<?php echo get_page_link($structure->id); ?>
```

I have already the conflict problem with the pages already created in wordpress who have the same id.

How i could create a single-page foreach results and have a permary-link to it with the name for exemple ?

hope someone could help.

Thanks a lot in advance

Here my custom index who display clubs :

```
<?php
 /**
    * Template Name: Structures
    */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                </tr>

            <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                $structures = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM structures");

                    foreach($structures as $structure) {  ?> 
                       <tr>
                              <th><img src="<?php echo $upload_dir['url']. "/" .$structure->lb_photo; ?>" height="100" width="100"/></th>
                                <td><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($structure->id); ?>"><?php echo $structure->nom_structure; ?></a></td> 
                      </tr>

                      <?php }

            ?>
            </table>


        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

I already started the single page code :

```
<?php
 /**
    * Template Name: Structure Single
    */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>

                </tr>

            <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                $structure = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM structures WHERE id = 1");
            ?> 

                       <tr>
                              <th><img src="<?php echo $upload_dir['url']. "/" .$structure->lb_photo; ?>" height="100" width="100"/></th>
                                <td><?php echo $structure->nom_structure ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $structure->adresse_structure ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $structure->cd_dept_structure ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $structure->tel_structure ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $structure->adresse_email_structure ?></td> 
                      </tr>
            </table>


        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: Why not use a custom post type?

Comment: Yes i could but should i need to create 146 pages in the custom post type ? 146 is the number of row results in the table

Comment: You can read this article. http://www.ethanjoachimeldridge.info/tech-blog/custom-permalinks-for-custom-templates

Comment: You can insert custom posts with `wp_insert_post`, you don't have to do it manually. You get the routing and meta data and taxonomies and all the integration with themes and plugins for free. That's the whole point of using a CMS- so you don't have to write a bunch of code to do the things it already does for you. What do you gain by using a custom table in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! i need to do this because i have an external table with data from a list of soccer clubs that i need to display on a wordpress website so i created and imported a new table on the database wordpress. Where do i need to do wp_insert_post ? i'm not a pro for this